# Find the closest/next $x\in\mathbb{N}$ that satisfies the equation $Ⲭ_{\mathbb{N}}(f(x)) = 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, numerical-methods, problem-solving, real-numbers

Find the closest/next $x\in\mathbb{N}$ that satisfies the equation $Ⲭ_ℕ(f(x)) = 1$, where $Ⲭ_\mathbb{N}(x): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is defined by
$$
\begin{cases}
  1 &\text{if } f(x) \in \mathbb{N}\\ 0 &\text{if } f(x) \notin \mathbb{N},
\end{cases}
$$

So $Ⲭ_ℕ(x)$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)

$f(x)$ can be choosen freely, but is known.

I am trying to ask if there is a method or an approach known, to solve - for any function (lets call it $f(x)$) that maps a $x \in ℕ$ into the real numbers - to find the next $x' \in ℕ$ so that $f(x')$ in the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) $Ⲭ_ℕ$ results in 1?

Some examples to show what I mean (if I find more, I will edit it):

- Square root of a linear function

  Let $f'(x) = \sqrt{k}$ and $x_1 = 3$ (e.g.)

  $x_{test} = f'(x_1) = \sqrt{3} \approx 1.73205081$

  $x_{solution} = \lceil{x_{test}}\rceil^2 = 2^2 = 4 \in ℕ \rightarrow Ⲭ_ℕ(f'(x_{solution})) = Ⲭ_ℕ(\sqrt{x_{solution}}) = Ⲭ_ℕ(2) = 1$

- Fractions

  Let $f''(x) = x * \frac{a}{b}$ and  $x_2 = 2, a = 6, b = 7$ (free to choose, just an example)

  $x_{test'} = f''(x_2) = 2 * \frac{a}{b} = \frac{12}{7}$

  $x_{solution'} = \lceil(\frac{12}{7}) / {a}\rceil * b = (\lceil\frac{12}{42}\rceil * 7) = 7 \in ℕ \rightarrow Ⲭ_ℕ(f''(x_{solution'})) = Ⲭ_ℕ(f''(7)) = Ⲭ_ℕ(6) = 1$

So is there any approach or method to solve this for any real function (e.g. square root with multiple variables: $\sqrt{(a+x)-b}$ or $\sqrt {x^2-q}$) that maybe requires more than rounding?

Thank you in advance!

R

Comment: No there isn't, if you don't know the function $f$ you can't know such smallest $x$.

Comment: I think this : $Ⲭ_ℕ(f(x)) = x$ is a typo. Shouldn't that be $Ⲭ_ℕ(f(x)) = 1$?

Comment: Yes, that is a typo! :) - Thank you, I fixed it.